# How do you make the browser go dim while showing a pop up

Tags: ajax, browser

I am quite often coming across sites that respond to a click on a What's This or a Gallery link by poping up a window in front of the original page, and making the original page go dim.

Is this a fancy AJAX trick?

Is it only likely to be supported in certain browsers?

And most importantly, how is it done?

Comment: I believe the technique is called 'lightbox'.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: lightbox is the name of a JS plugin that allows to show bigger verions of images directly on the page using a "dim" effect as described in the question. But it's not the name of the effect itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing more than adding a `<DIV>` that covers the entire screen, and give it a black background. jQuery's UI library will handle this for you automatically.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Or you can do it with basic HTML/CSS/jQuery like this:

```
div.modal-bg { 
  background:#000; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:0; left:0; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  z-index:10; 
}
```

```
<div class="modal-bg"></div>
```

```
$(function(){
  $("div.modal-bg").fadeTo("slow", .5);
});
```

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eys3d/741/) and [here](http://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/) another with **more overlay effects**. Hope helps.